# Akka actor ask pattern does not work as expected

Tags: scala, akka

Actor B contains reference to actor A called `senderr`. Actor A `ask`s actor B, waits the response and prints it. However it does not receive response. Why? It must print number 4 at the console but it doesn't.

```
class A(b: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)

  b ! 1

  def receive = {
    case 2 => (b ? 3).map(println)
  }
}

class B extends Actor {

  var senderr : ActorRef = null

  def receive = {
    case 1 =>
      senderr = sender()
      sender ! 2
    case 3 =>
      senderr ! 4
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("test")
  val b = system.actorOf(Props[B])
  val a = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[A], b))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask` basically creates a temporary micro-actor with the single purpose of receiving one response of type `Any`

When `B` receives `3` it sends `4` to `senderr` which refers to `A`. However `A` does not have a match for `4`. In order for `(b ? 3).map(println)` to receive the `4`, `B` has to send it to `sender()`, which at that time refers to the temporary actor set up by `ask`:

```
case 3 => sender ! 4
```

Alternatively, you could have a `case 4` in `A` but then you wouldn't even need to use `ask`